# How to migrate specific migration file in PHP laravel - Nothing to migrate message

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I have a migration file that I want to run, (only this file not all the migrations file).
[image]

I run this command:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2019_08_21_225302_delete_encode_crids_ssp.php
```

In vscode I open the terminal and get this message:
[image]

How I can make it to run this specific file, (not want all the files just this file)

Project tree:
[image]

this is the code:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('ssp', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('encode_crids');
        });
    }
```

try to do again and get this:
[image]

and again:
[image]

Comment: Check your `migration` table to whether its already migrated?

Comment: Ok, so what is the migration doing? Show us the code

Comment: the column still exists in db

Comment: @Bastian no in the `migration` table

Comment: not sure what you want me to display

Comment: @Bastian Just re-run it. chek my answer will fix the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ***re-run the migration with force***, use `migrate:refresh`

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/2019_08_21_225302_delete_encode_crids_ssp.php
```

---

With using **`refresh()`** command
[image]

With using **`fresh()`** command
[image]

Comment: Worked? Any update?

Comment: see the update I edite

Comment: it's `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: nothing work sorry

Comment: @Bastian, it can't be. Before I post some thing, I test it for myself. check the results in edit

Comment: yes tnx it solved